# Input value does not replace global scope

Tags: javascript

Input value does not replace global scope. I'm trying to have a default number on a variable. I would like to enter a number into an input on the browser and then update that variable.

```
// VARIABLES
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const unsplashURL = 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/';
let rows = 3
const input = document.querySelector('#number')
const button = document.querySelector('.button')

for (let i = 0; i < rows * 3; i++) {
    const img = document.createElement('img')
    img.src = `${ unsplashURL }${ getRandomSize() }`
    container.appendChild(img)
}

button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    let rows = input.value
    input.value = ''
})

// FUNCTIONS
function getRandomSize() {
    return `${ getRandomNr() }x${ getRandomNr() }`
}

function getRandomNr() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) + 300
}
```

Comment: remove *let* from *let rows = input.value*. so it might be replaced like *rows = input.value*

Comment: please share an html with script above as a snippet and show us what kind of result you are looking for. @phil

Comment: @GeorgeWang, I've tried that but it's the same

Comment: @Alona, I'm trying to have a default number of rows that display some images (in this case 3 is the default number of rows). I would like to have an input on the UI where I can enter the number of rows that I want to have displayed and then submit the number by clicking on a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@phil_Hinch, here are the problems you have.

1. JavaScript code is not re-running automatically. You need to define function like `setupGrid` and call this function every time after you update `rows`.
2. On button click listener, you wrote `let rows = input.value`. Which means new variable `rows` declared for that code block. This will not update `let rows = 3`. You need to remove `let` to update global `rows`.

Please check following example

```js
// VARIABLES
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const unsplashURL = 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/';
let rows = 3
const input = document.querySelector('#number')
const button = document.querySelector('.button')

function setupGrid() {
    container.innerHTML = ''
    for (let i = 0; i < rows * 3; i++) {
        const img = document.createElement('img')
        img.src = `${ unsplashURL }${ getRandomSize() }`
        container.appendChild(img)
    }
}

button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    rows = input.value
    input.value = ''
    setupGrid()
})

// FUNCTIONS
function getRandomSize() {
    return `${ getRandomNr() }x${ getRandomNr() }`
}

function getRandomNr() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) + 300
}

setupGrid();
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}

.container img {
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
</div>
<input id="number" type="number" />
<button class="button">update</button>
```